# Android: How to Format Date and Time Strings correctly?

Tags: java, android, date, time, format

How should I correctly format **Date** and **Time** Strings for the Android platform?

Here is some code:

```
String path = getFilesDir().getPath();
String filePath = path + "/somefile.xml";
File file = new File(filePath);
Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());
String filelastModDate = "Updated: " + lastModDate.toString();
```

Comment: For what exactly? For some system library to read? For display to humans?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`. If you have problems, ask a more specific question.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format it various way...

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
String currentTime = sdf.format(date);
```

Here you can put other format like

k:mm

h:mm

h:mm dd/MM/yyyy
  etc.....

check this.... http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks @receme  I used: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @receme  I solved it. like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a",Locale.getDefault());
String currentTime = sdf.format(date);
Log.i(LOGTAG,"Current Time: " + currentTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(    // Parse milliseconds count to a moment in UTC.
    file.lastModified()  // A count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
)                        // Returns a `Instant` object.
.atZone(                 // Adjust from UTC to some time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.format(                 // Generate a `String`.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )  // Specify how long or abbreviated.
    .withLocale( Locale.JAPAN )  // Specify a `Local` to determine human language and cultural norms used in localizing.
)                        // Returns a `String`.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

The `File.lastModified` method returns a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = file.lastModified() ;
```

Parse that number as a modern *java.time* object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

Generate a `String` to represent that values using standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  // Generate a `String` in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-07-16T22:40:39.937Z

To view the same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> 2018-07-17T10:40:39.937+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

Let *java.time* automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> mardi 17 juillet 2018 à 10:40:39 heure normale de la Nouvelle-Zélande

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Joda-Time

Install third-party library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

By default, Joda-Time outputs strings in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That format is intuitively understandable by virtually anybody worldwide.

Search StackOverflow.com for many more examples.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTime now = new DateTime();
System.out.println( now );
```

When run…

```
2013-12-05T19:55:43.897-08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my share here.

Note that the user can set his preferred format in the settings. Example on how to retrieve:

```
static DateFormat getUserDateFormat(Context context) {
    if (mUserDateFormat == null)
        mUserDateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context.getApplicationContext());
    return mUserDateFormat;
}
```

See also `...getTimeFormat`

You then have a java DateFormat to use with above mentioned examples.

Furthermore, Android contains it's own TextFormat class, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/package-summary.html

This may look like:

```
static String getAppExpiredString() {
    String date = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getAppContext()).format(App_Main.APP_RUN_TILL.getTime());
    return getAppContext().getString(R.string.app_expired) + " " + date + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though, The question is very old, but it may help one who wants it Kotlin version of this answer. Here I take a empty file name **`DateUtil`** and create a function called **`getDateString()`** which has 3 arguments.

```
1st argument : Your input date
2nd argument : Your input date pattern
3rd argument : Your wanted date pattern
```

`DateUtil.kt`

```
object DatePattern {
    const val YEAR_MONTH_DAY = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    const val DAY_MONTH_YEAR = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    const val RFC3339 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
}

fun getDateString(date: String, inputDatePattern: String, outputDatePattern: String): String {
    return try {
        val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat(inputDatePattern, getDefault())
        val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat(outputDatePattern, getDefault())

        outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

And now use this method in your activity/fuction/dataSourse Mapper to get Date in String format like this

```
getDate("2022-01-18T14:41:52Z", RFC3339, DAY_MONTH_YEAR)
```

and output will be like this

```
18-01-2022
```